# Is "would" incompatible with "I'm not sure"?

Tags: modal-verbs, modality

Is "would" incompatible with "I'm not sure"?
If so, do you know why?

> A: Where's John now?

> B: I'm not sure. He would be at home now.

> A: When will John come back?

> B: I'm not sure. He would be back by seven.

Comment: The short answer is: they are compatible. Explaining it is difficult. I tried explaining it once before in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/41495/6700). See especially the 4th example.

Comment: I think those expression would be more idiomatic with "would usually". The would is conditional, and "usually" sets the condition. In the first sentence of this comment, I used "would be more idiomatic", and the condition was "with 'would usually'".

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Is it okay to use "I'm not sure" with "but he would  normally be at home now"?

Comment: @Apollyon Yes, "normally" qualifies "would". Qualifying the whole with "I'm not sure, but..." is quite idiomatic.