# Can "should" mean "if"?

Tags: conditional-constructions, inversion

> STUART:
>   I think you have some great ideas but where you lack is in details and structure—both areas which I excel at. Last night I came up with some terms and conditions, and **should** you feel like you can abide by those, I'd be happy to come back to work with you but not for you. I want to be VP of Project Development. I want more responsibility and I want to be in the room when decisions are made. Give it a look over and give me a call tomorrow, and let me know what we can do.

I can't understand the meaning of "should" in the above context. Does it mean "if"?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Long answer: [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/44404/6700) (possibly more than you want to know).

Comment: I find only a failed attempt to feign nuance in that passage in this (clumsy) phrase: "should you feel like you can abide by those". Considering the bluntness of the repeated "I want...I want...I want" and the imperatives "Give it a look over" and "Give me a call", it means "if" with a generous dash of "unless".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*should* is the conditional form of the auxiliary (modal) *shall*, and is more polite form of saying "*if you [shall] feel like you can abide...*"

It is very similar to the difference between (future)

> "Will you join us for dinner?

and, the more polite (conditional)

> "Would you join us for dinner?"

The conditional is a softer, more polite (and nebulous) way of asking a question.

There are some other examples of the use of *should* on [Word Reference:Should you have any question](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=292455), including a good explanation of why the *if* disappears, due to **auxiliary subject inversion*:

> It's just another way of expressing the second (or third) conditional
>   by the means of auxiliary-subject inversion. More examples If I were
>   to find a treasure I'd buy a castle.
>   --> Were I to find a treasure, .....
>
> If he hadn't been there, we would have lost the game
>   ---> Had he not been there, we.....
>
> In both sentences we have inverted the subject and the auxiliary (or
>   modal). Plus we no longer need the if.
>
> It's both more idiomatic (in the sense that this wording is specific
>   to English) and slightly more formal.

I hope that helps.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

The difference if very subtle, but using "if" in this context would sound a little bit snappy and rude. The tone sounds like "if you feel like you can do what I say" rather than "if you're happy with my suggestions". By using the word "should" instead, the speaker is focusing on what he would do with the listener's cooperation in a hypothetical sort of way.